# Should I add a click handler to Gatsby Link?

Tags: gatsby

We need to trigger a function when our website users click on a button (for Mixpanel analytics). Is it a good idea to just update our Gatsby Link components with an onClick handler?

I'm particularly mindful of accessibility issues.

Thanks

```js
// What we currently do
const Component = () => {
  return <Link to="/">Home</Link>
}

// What we're thinking of doing
const Component = () => {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    triggerFunction();
    navigate("/")
  }
  return <Link to="/" onClick={handleClick}>Home</Link>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It sounds like adding the onClick would work better for us than using
> onRouteUpdate (as we need to specifically know the button that was
> clicked). To clarify, using onClick on a Link is valid syntax? And we
> don't need to do any sort of work to delay the page change to be sure
> that the onClick fires and completes before the page change?

It's not a good idea using Gatsby's `Link` component to change and prevent its default behavior. It can lead to some inconsistencies and undesired behavior.

As you pointed out, `onRouteUpdate` would be the cleanest solution so far, but if it's not an option, I'd say it's preferable to use a regular `<div>` (or another tag) to make the navigation. To me, it doesn't make sense to use a `Link` and change completely its behavior to perform some actions before the main action (preventing it and navigating through `navigate()` function) because you are not taking any advantage of using it.

I like the idea of using your own custom navigation component but not using a `Link` which it won't behave as `Link`.

```
const Component = () => {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    triggerFunction();
    navigate("/")
  }
  return <a href="/" onClick={handleClick}>Home</a>
}
```

Comment: It seems like this solution would be pretty bad from an accessibility point of view. Essentially, I want something that looks and acts like a Link, but just has the extra step of calling a function before page change.

Comment: Even customizing the `div` with the proper ARIA attributes? If it's also not an option,  I'd say that the only option you have it's using your proposal, but it's not what I like in terms of code scalability

Comment: What are the scaling issues we will run into?

Comment: (1/2) That you are attaching your (business) logic to a Gatsby's link, and it's a weakness of the code because any change on their side can compromise your component. I normally prefer built-in solutions, but in this case, since you are tweaking the "default" behavior of Gatsby's link, anyone can't ensure that in each update the `Link` will still be behaving as is. It's a long-shot to guess, but it's worth mention all the scenarios.

Comment: (2/2)You have three options here (I guess): 1) Customizing an anchor to prevent the navigation. 2) Customizing the `Link` to prevent the navigation. 3) Customize a `div` (for example) to give the required ARIA attributes

Comment: Thank you, that's nice and clear :) In your example, you've used to="" in the div, should this not be href=""? And could we not use an a tag instead of the div tag? I suppose this would be the option 1 that you've suggested?

Comment: Sorry you're right. It was a typo from copy/pasting your proposal. If you choose an `a` it should be `href` as you pointed. If you choose to customize a `div` it won't have any attribute

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use anchor elements (`Link` component internally renders anchor element) as a buttons, but if you want to call some analytics function you just could call your `triggerFunction` without preventing default Link behaviour:

```js
const Component = () => {
  return <Link to="/" onClick={triggerFunction}>Home</Link>
}
```

Here you can read more about accessibility of anchor tags: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#accessibility

Other (in my opinion better) solution is to use `onRouteUpdate` API of Gatsby Browser API: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#onRouteUpdate

Comment: It sounds like adding the onClick would work better for us than using onRouteUpdate (as we need to specifically know the button that was clicked).

To clarify, using onClick on a Link is valid syntax? And we don't need to do any sort of work to delay the page change to be sure that the onClick fires and completes before the page change?